# VF page won't save with a conditional page action

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to create a Visualforce page that will overide the delete button on leads so that only certain users are allowed to delete leads.  I keep geting errors when I try to save the page.  I have pasted my Visualforce markup below.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<apex:page action="{!if($User.Alias !='KKing','HLemons','Dink','DPearse',
    null,
    urlFor($Action.Lead.Delete, $CurrentPage.Parameters.id, [retURL='/00Q'], true)
    )
    }"
  standardController="Lead">
     <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:PageMessage summary="You are not allowed to delete Leads"
            severity="Warning"
            strength="3"/>
        <apex:pageMessages />
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It would likely be helpful if you posted what your errors were as well.

Comment: I speculate on the ACTION attribute in the page tag. Are you getting the error: "Syntax error" or "Incorrect number of parameters" or so?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first line to:

```
<apex:page action="{!if(and($User.Alias != 'KKing', $User.Alias != 'HLemons', $User.Alias != 'Dink', $User.Alias != 'DPearse'),
```

will allow the page to compile.

Answer (score 0):

If the only objective of the VF page is to prevent users from deleting the records, the better option would be to write a Before Delete trigger and add an error message there.